# SQL Server Profiler filter - does this have any impact/load on server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

When we add a database name filter and run the SQL Server Profiler trace, does the profiler look at all databases on the instance and only show the filtered db to the user? Or does it only look at the filtered database?

I am interested to know whether filtering by database name would put lesser performance load on the server? Or is the filter only for the purpose of displaying the filtered results and doesn't affect performance/load on server?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Profiler is awesome, but also one of those unique gems which will gladly chew up every available cycle and bit of ram to continuously monitor the server in real time. I almost always limit the session to a single `SPID` when possible, but I have also used `database name` and `procedure text`